# Bash : Date comparison in IF condition not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, unix

```
echo "Input start date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) :"
read start_date_time
echo "Input end date and time(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) :" 
read end_date_time
  
while [[ $(date -d "$start_date_time" +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M 2>/dev/null) != $start_date_time || $(date -d "$end_date_time" +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M 2>/dev/null) != $end_date_time ]]

do
    echo "Invalid input! Please reinsert in the correct format."
    echo "Start date and time :"
    read start_date_time
    echo "End date and time :"
    read end_date_time

    if [[ $(date -d "$start_date_time" +%s) -gt $(date -d "$end_date_time" +%s) ]]
    then
        echo "Start datetime cannot be greater than end datetime."
    continue
    fi

done
```

The `if` condition in this script does not work, it doesn't trigger the `echo` line even though when `$start_date_time` is greater than the `$end_date_time`. I even tried the method below but to no avail:

`if [[ $start_date_time > $end_date_time ]]`

I have ran out of ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Convert your dates to seconds since epoch. Bash itself doesn't really understand how to parse dates, and your while condition has syntax errors. Did you run shellcheck on it?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I did convert it to seconds as you can see. I also ran a shellcheck on it but there are no errors with the ```if``` condition itself. What's weird is that if I place the ```if``` condition outside of the loop, it works.

Comment: Pro tip: for debugging, add a `set -x` to your script to get it to print the (expanded) commands it is executing.

Comment: Doing that would help you recognize that the comparison you're asking about isn't even reached when you have entered valid dates.  It is inside the body of the loop, which is executed only if one or both of the dates is incorrectly formatted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah yes thank you. That makes perfect sense. That is why the ```if``` condition is triggered when it is placed outside of the loop.

Comment: consider updating the question to include a sample set of `start_date_time` and `end_date_time` values for which the script *`does not work`*

Answer (score 1):

As John Bollinger noted in his comment, if you put in *valid* datetime values at the top, it never enters the loop, and so never checks that end is greater than start.

If you put in an invalid value at the start, it enters the loop and asks for new values, then checks start > end and `continue`s, but the `while` only tests whether both dates are *valid*, so the loop exits without letting you re-enter them.

Also, your code currently allows start and end to be the same without complaint, which might not be what you want.

Consider refactoring with a function to eliminate the redundant code:

```
take_datetime() {
  local dt= prompt="${1:-Please input a valid date and time(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) :}"
  read -p "$prompt" dt
  until date -d "$dt" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
  do dt=$(take_datetime "$prompt")
  done
}

declare -i stst=0 etst=0
until (( etst > stst ))
do ((stst)) && printf "\n *** Ending datetime must be greater than starting datetime ***\n"
   start=$( take_datetime "Input START date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) : " )
   end=$(   take_datetime "Input END   date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) : " )
   stst=$(  date -d "$start" "+%s" )
   etst=$(  date -d "$end"   "+%s" )
done

echo "START: $start"
echo "END  : $end"
```

This currently allows any *valid* date/time format to be used, and converts it to the format you want.

```
$: ./tst
Input START date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) : 1234-11-12 11:13
Input END   date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) : 11/12/1234 11:14
START: 1234-11-12 11:13
END  : 1234-11-12 11:14
```

This does leave the possibility of confusion over month and day, such as European vs. American norms. To force the input format as you were doing before, update the function:

```
take_datetime() {
  local dt= prompt="${1:-Please input a valid date and time(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) :}"
  read -p "$prompt" dt
  until date -d "$dt" >/dev/null && [[ $( date -d "$dt" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" ) == "$dt" ]]
  do dt=$( take_datetime "Please check your format; $prompt" )
  done
  echo "$dt"
}
```

That should do it:

```
$: ./tst
Input START date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) : foo
date: invalid date ‘foo’
Please check your format; Input START date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) : 1234-11-12 11:13
Input END   date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) : 11/12/1234 11:14
Please check your format; Input END   date and time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm) : 1234-11-12 11:14
START: 1234-11-12 11:13
END  : 1234-11-12 11:14
```

Namerefs would probably make it prettier...